# Search for file in AWK Command Prompt

Tags: awk, command-prompt

I have this directory that is loaded with hundreds of .txt files. The problem is, there are a ton of filenames. I'm looking for a way to search in the directory and print all files with a name similar to what I'm seeking. ie,

awk find like file name.

Comment: This has nothing to do with awk, it's entirely about whatever OS/shell you're using as THAT is what determines the file names to pass to awk or any other command. Remove the awk tag and tag it with your OS and shell to get the right answer.

Comment: Apologies for the vague question. I'm using Window's Command Prompt. As for the sample code, I'm testing to find a file named "cheetah.txt"  in command prompt, once I've navigated to the proper directory path where the files are stored, I've used the following syntax attempts: find .-cheetah  (returned with error)    find .-name "cheetah" (returned with error)   find .-"cheetah"  (returned with error)

Answer (score 0):

man find.  awk does sounds like the right tool for this job.  you are probably looking for something like this:

find . -name *pattern*

Comment: or even `ls *pattern*`